# Como faço para receber em uma variável o key de um array no controller laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou mandando um parâmetro em uma `view href="{{route('products.index', 'E')}}"` eu preciso receber esse parâmetro `'E'` em uma variável no `controller` e enviar via `compact();` em outra `view`

**segue minha rota:**

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

**segue meu controller:**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {         
        $btn = $request->all();
        dd($btn);
//        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);
//        
//        return view('products.index', compact('products','btn'))
//                ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1)* 5);
    }

nesse dd($btn); a variável me retorna null como mostra abaixo.

array:1 [▼
  "E" => null
]
```

nesse caso gostaria de receber na variável `$btn` a informação `'E'`, alguém sabe como poderia está fazendo isso?

Obs: estou usando controller resource.

Comment: Conseguir o que queria fazer, apenas coloquei o parametro assim {{route('products.index', 'id=E')}} deu certo recuperei o parametro no controller

Answer (score 0):

Aqui você terá que fazer uma por uma, digite no console para ver as rotas que o resource está criando: 
`php artisan route:list`

Você vai ter que remover esta rota e criar novas.

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

exemplo de rota para pegar este parâmetro:

`Route:get('products/{nomedoparametro}', 'ProductController@pegarParam')->name('products.getparam');`

na view você faz assim de onde for para enviar (um form por exemplo): 
`{{route('products.getparam', ['nomedoparametro' => 'informacao que deseja enviar'])}}`

no controlador você pode fazer assim:

```
public function pegarParam($nomedoparametro){
  return view('view',compact('nomedoparametro'));
}
```

Referência : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters